# What's the difference between "tell somebody something" and "tell somebody about something"?

Tags: differences

We often say "He told me a story/the news" (1) without a preposition but we use "about" in "Please tell me about him/your holiday" (2).

My 10 year-old daughter asked me the difference between (1) and (2) but I didn't know how to explain.

When do we use "tell about"?

Comment: 'He told me the news' means 'He broke / related the news to me'. 'He told me a story' means 'He read out a story to me' or more generally 'He related a story to me'. // 'He told me about _Jaws_' means either 'He informed me of the existence of _Jaws_' or 'He gave me various details (eg when and where showing; story-line) relating to _Jaws_'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the word *about*, you're asking about applying the verb *tell* to an arbitrary noun. This doesn't work in all situations.

For example, a *holiday* is the gestalt of a stretch of time people spend together doing (or not doing) something. They can be *taken*, *wasted*, *enjoyed* and so on, but it sounds unusual to talk about *telling* holidays.

What one does instead is *describe* holidays - telling someone *about* them.

> **about** *preposition*
>   1 On the subject of; concerning.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/about)

*News*, on the other hand, is *information*. It is therefore something that one can *tell* or *listen to* in a natural manner. One can also describe (tell someone *about*) the news, but that's a step removed. For example, you might *tell* your friend the news that you've landed a job. This might include who employed you, what perks you'll get, where you'll work, etc. If you wanted to tell someone *about* that news, strictly-speaking you're conveying *meta-information*. In that case, the things you speak about might be which TV channel it was on, or the number of minutes it took to convey the news.

You ask:

> When do we use "tell about"?

You use *tell ... about X* when you're trying to describe 'X' (convey meta-information about 'X'), as opposed to conveying 'X' directly.